# My Flutter code is causing me error while the execution of the code for generating it as app

Tags: flutter

Launching lib\main.dart on Redmi 8A Dual in debug mode...
Building with Flutter multidex support enabled.
C:\Users\N!CK$.gradle\caches\transforms-3\753fa60a6479e7cd833816e6aebf784b\transformed\jetified-play-services-measurement-api-21.5.0-api.jar!\META-INF\java.com.google.android.gmscore.integ.client.measurement_api_measurement_api.kotlin_module: error: module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
> Compilation error. See log for more details

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13m 6s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                            807.4s

┌─ Flutter Fix ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                                                                               │
│ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then update D:\app_development\my_newapp\android\build.gradle: │
│ ext.kotlin_version = ''                                                                                                              │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

so basically i tried changing the kotlin to latest verion but still it shows this kind of error even if try changing it to another version and i expect solve this error even though i changed the version which is to be requied as per error

Answer (score 0):

check the compatible Kotlin Gradle plugin from this URL:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html
Also run with :
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter run